# c# Draw Image (Scaled) to Graphics, does not interpolate correctly. Fixes?

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+, interpolation, stretch

I have an image that is 1px wide, and some height. I need to draw this image across the entire width of the control on it's OnPaint event. I get it to draw, however not correctly. It seems like when it stretches it, it doesn't actually fill all the pixels. As if the interpolation is off. Is there a way to say "stop being smart, just draw it already"? I see no InterpolationMode.Off or .None in the options for the graphics object.

I can confirm I actually drawing the full width by using an image of width X where X is the same width as the control. Then when it draws, it covers the full area as normal. However this control is resized all the time, and to save memory and all that jazz using 1px wide images is quite normal in the web world. This is for a desktop C# application though. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok I figured out the magic keywords:

```
g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half;
```

This coupled with setting the Interpolation Mode to NearestNeighbour allows for a full block to be drawn.

Without setting the Interpolation mode, you get weird blending (expected).
Without setting the PixelOffsetMode, the nearest neighbour algorithm has no neighbour to compare to on a blank paint and therefore only draws half the image, for half the width. Setting it to offset half, moves everything over by -0.5px, and allows this algorithm to work for block textures.

Comment: I had the same problem and after trying several variations of PixelOffsetMode and InterpolationMode, this is what worked for me.

For those searching via Google: Setting PixelOffsetMode to Half lets graphics.DrawImage(...) resize an image (like in MS Paint) without any aliasing and fills the destination size/rectangle with what you specify.

This is good if you want to overlay a single colour image/pattern when you don't care about artifacts/blending (because its one solid colour, there wont be any).

Answer (score 0):

InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor is what you want to use in this case.

Comment: I have tried this, and it gives me a solid bitmap for exactly 1/2 the width, then nothing. Other modes give varying transparency after halfway, but InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor only draws 0.5*wanted_width.

Comment: That's not true, it must be a problem elsewhere in your code.  I tested it myself just to be sure.  The interpolation mode has nothing to do with the width of the drawn image.

Comment: It does when there is nothing else drawn. Check below for my answer, it has to do with the PixelOffset as well. It is easily reproducable. Take any control, override its OnPaint event, draw a 1px wide image for the full width, and it will only show up 50% wide. Now set the PixelOffset, and it shows 100%. This is with Visual Studio 2010, and .NET 4.0 on many many different controls, all act the same.

Comment: I did test it and did not see that behavior.