# Resize image 2x2 pixels to say 4x4 pixels keeping colours the same

Tags: c#, image, resize

Please imagine I have a very simple chequerboard image.

Here I represent the image with letters as pixels: black pixel 'B', white pixel 'W'

Here is the starting 2x2 pixel image:

```
BW
WB
```

I want  to resize the image, lets say by scale of 2x to give me :

```
BBWW
BBWW
WWBB
WWBB
```

or scale 4x

```
BBBBWWWW
BBBBWWWW
WWWWBBBB
WWWWBBBB
```

So that the pixel colours are not dithered in any way at all.

I have tried this in C# but the image is a mess, all dithered, I need to learn how to do this without dithering/color change.

Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Text;

namespace PageTwine
{
    public partial class RandonGiff : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // create 2x2 chequerboard:
            Bitmap oBitmap = new Bitmap(2, 2);
            Graphics oGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(oBitmap);

            // color black pixels (i think the default is black but this helps to explain)
            SolidBrush oBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255));
            oGraphic.FillRectangle(oBrush, 0, 0, 1, 1);
            oGraphic.FillRectangle(oBrush, 1, 1, 1, 1);

            //color white pixels
            oBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0));
            oGraphic.FillRectangle(oBrush, 0, 1, 1, 1);
            oGraphic.FillRectangle(oBrush, 1, 0, 1, 1);

            // expand to 4x4
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(4, 4);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            {
                // I don't know what these settings should be :

                graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;

                //draw the image into the target bitmap 
                graphics.DrawImage(oBitmap, 0, 0, result.Width, result.Height);
            }

            //send image directly to the browser
            Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
            result.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);

        }
    }

}
```

The result is a dithered image, but I need a clean crisp chequerboard effect.
Please can you help me.

## EDIT:07/02/12

Thanks for the suggestions so far but I am still searching without finding a solution.

I have created a demo page so you can see the results for yourself.

The URL for the demo is :

http://www.leansoftware.net/servicedesk/publicadhoc/randomgif.aspx?columns=3&rows=3

The demo will create a chequerboard with initial columns x rows as pixels, then enlarge to a gif image 300x300 px.

You will see that colours are distorted/bitty - this I am trying to solve.

Here is the source code for the demo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Linq;


    public partial class RandomGif : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public class Coordinates
        {
            public int x { get; set; }
            public int y { get; set; }
        }

        static Random rand = new Random();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Output type gif
            int iwidth;
            int iheight;
            int bits;
            Response.ContentType = "image/gif";

            // Get parameters
            if (Request.QueryString["count"] != null)
            {
                bits = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["count"]);
                int square = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(bits + Math.Floor(bits / 4.0))));
                iwidth = square;
                iheight = square;
                bits = (square * square)-1;
            }
            else
                if (Request.QueryString["rows"] != null && Request.QueryString["columns"] != null)
                {
                    iwidth = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["columns"]);
                    iheight = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["rows"]);
                    bits = (iwidth * iheight);
                }
                else {
                    return;
                }
        if (bits > 1000){
        Response.Write("Please specify a grid <= 1000 pixels");
        return;
        }

            int plotCount = 0;

            //web safe colors : 00, 33, 66, 99, CC, FF;
            List<int> webSafeColor = new List<int>();
            webSafeColor.Add(0); //00
            webSafeColor.Add(51);//33
            webSafeColor.Add(102);//66
            webSafeColor.Add(153);//99
            webSafeColor.Add(204);//CC
            webSafeColor.Add(255);//FF

            // Create a structure to hold all possible coordinates
            var Grid = new List<Coordinates>();
            for (int xi = 1; xi <= iwidth; xi++)
            {
                for (int yi = 1; yi <= iheight; yi++)
                {
                    Grid.Add(new Coordinates { x = xi, y = yi });
                    plotCount++;
                }
            }

            //create a new Bitmap object
            Bitmap oBitmap = new Bitmap(iwidth, iheight);

            //create a new Graphics object, which will allow us to draw on our bitmap:
            Graphics oGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(oBitmap);


            //fill the image rectangle with n bits
            for (int i = 1; i <= bits; i++)
            {
                //Random rand = new Random();
                int row = rand.Next(Grid.Count());

                // random red
                int ircolor = webSafeColor[rand.Next(5)];

                // random green
                int igcolor = webSafeColor[rand.Next(5)];

                // random blue
                int ibcolor = webSafeColor[rand.Next(5)];

                Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(ircolor, igcolor, ibcolor);
                SolidBrush oBrush = new SolidBrush(randomColor);
                oGraphic.FillRectangle(oBrush, Grid[row].x - 1, Grid[row].y - 1, 1, 1);

        // Delete this coordinate#
                Grid.Remove(Grid[row]);
            }

            // resize image
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(300, 300);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            {
                //set the resize quality modes to high quality 
                graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.AssumeLinear;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half; 

                //draw the image into the target bitmap 
                graphics.DrawImage(oBitmap, 0, 0, result.Width, result.Height);
            }

            //send image directly to the browser
            Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
            result.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);

        }
    }
```

If you can suggest modifications we can try them out and see if it fixes the problem.

Thanks Richard

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible duplicate of [c# Draw Image (Scaled) to Graphics, does not interpolate correctly. Fixes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413050/c-sharp-draw-image-scaled-to-graphics-does-not-interpolate-correctly-fixes)

You need to add:

```
graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half;
```

Alternately, you could use

```
graphics.DrawImage(oBitmap, 0, 0, result.Width * 2, result.Height * 2);
```

to achieve a similar effect of forcing the brush to fill without warping at the right-bottom image edges.

**Update:**

Adding link for creating indexed images with a custom color palette.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319061

Comment: Unfortuanately the problem persists.   I have added a live demo so you can see what's happening: please see the update in the original question.

Comment: What happens when you choose image/png? It looks as if the color table used by your gif image does not include the colors you're using to draw on the source image. The effect you're seeing is called Dithering.

Comment: Yes! that worked. Thankyou Jim.   The project requires the final output to be an animated gif, I don't think png animation is supported in all browsers.    So now I need to work out how to add the colours used to the color table, can I ask if you know how to do that. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
```

Comment: Its better, but a strange result http://leansoftware.net/ServiceDesk/PublicAdHoc/result.png

Comment: using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            {
                // I don't know what these settings should be :

                //graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.AssumeLinear;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
                //graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;

                //draw the image into the target bitmap 
                graphics.DrawImage(oBitmap, 0, 0, result.Width, result.Height);
            }

Comment: The only other thing I can recommend is using  System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality

Comment: I have edited the code in the question to give you the full code behind code needed to run the example.   I tried changing to high quality Brad but I still have this result http://leansoftware.net/ServiceDesk/PublicAdHoc/result.png

Comment: I added line of code:  graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;http://leansoftware.net/ServiceDesk/PublicAdHoc/result_color.png    When using an rgb color however I get the dithering effect.    I am using using random values for RGB, perhaps I need to use web safe colors I don't know but why I don't get solid colours I do not understand.  (this comment editor box is useless for pasting code)

Comment: It won't let me edit, the above link should be http://leansoftware.net/ServiceDesk/PublicAdHoc/result_incolor.png

Comment: Notice the image is 4x4 pixels - zoomed so you can see the effect http://leansoftware.net/ServiceDesk/PublicAdHoc/result_incolor.png

Comment: I tried changing to web safe colours, but same problem, colours not solid when expanded :(